# Invalid constructor token C++ Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

I am getting the error

> C:\Users\Jake\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Sonar\Sonar.cpp:3:13: error: expected >constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
>   Sonar::Sonar(trigLeft,echoLeft,trigRight, echoRight)
>   Error compiling.

I have no idea what's causing this, there was at one point a curly brace missing but I re-added that. The code is as follows

Sonar.cpp:

```
#include "Sonar.h"

Sonar::Sonar(trigLeft,echoLeft,trigRight, echoRight) {
    pinMode(triggerPinLeft,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(triggerPinRight,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(echoPinLeft,INPUT);
    pinMode(echoPinRight,INPUT);

    triggerPinLeft = trigLeft;
    echoPinLeft = echoRight;
    triggerPinRight = trigRight;
    echoPinRight = echoRight;

}



void Sonar::Ping() {

  digitalWrite(triggerPinLeft, LOW);
  digitalWrite(triggerPinRight, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(triggerPinLeft, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(triggerPinRight, HIGH);;
  delayMicroseconds(5);
  digitalWrite(triggerPinLeft, LOW);
  digitalWrite(triggerPinRight, LOW);

  // Read EchoPins

  long durationLeft = pulseIn(echoPinLeft, HIGH);
  long durationRight = pulseIn(echoPinRight, HIGH);

  // convert the time into a distance

  cmLeft = microsecondsToCentimeters(durationLeft);
  cmRight - microsecondsToCentimeters(durationRight);

  delay(100);
}

long Sonar::microsecondsToCentimeters(long microseconds) {
    // The speed of sound is 340 m/s or 29 microseconds per centimeter.

    return microseconds / 58;
}
```

Sonar.h:

```
#ifndef Sonar_h
#define Sonar_h

#include "Arduino.h"

class Sonar {
  public:
    Sonar(int,int,int,int);
    long cmLeft,cmRight;
    void Ping();
  private:
    const int triggerPinLeft,echoPinLeft,triggerPinRight,echoPinRight;
    long microsecondsToInches(long microseconds);
    long microsecondsToCentimeters(long microseconds);
};

#endif
```

And finally Sonar.ino (This is for the Arduino, it is working fine I believe)

```
#include <Sonar.h>

Sonar sonar(20,21,22,23);
void setup() {
// put your setup code here, to run once:
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  sonar.Ping();
  long sonarLeftDistance = sonar.cmLeft;
  long sonarRightDistance = sonar.cmRight;

}
```

That's all the code. The Arduino bit is largely irrelevant.

Comment: You probably meant to write `Sonar::Sonar(int trigLeft,int echoLeft,int trigRight, int echoRight)` :-P ... Replicate function signatures with the correct types from your declarations, simple like that.

Comment: That's not _"brilliant"_, but very, very basic stuff (I'm even feeling dumb answering it). _'code'_ Isn't a error message and you probably should ask another question, because that seems to be an unrelated issue.

Comment: Sorry about that, Im relatively new to SO, just come out of uni and had mainly asked lecturers/ MSDN due to the C#..

Comment: Im just getting now "C:\Users\Jake\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Sonar\Sonar.cpp:13:15: error: assignment of read-only member 'Sonar::echoPinRight' echoPinRight = echoRight; ^ Error compiling." For every data member, Im not great at c++ as you can tell, more C and C#...

Comment: Decided I just don't care enough about them being const's , made them normal ints and its fine now. They are never re-assigned anyway, they are simply pins on the arduino anyway. Thanks a lot for your help. sorry if I was embarrassingly dumb, I just had no idea what to do.
 I DO know that methods require the types, just brain was locked in on looking for a curly brace. C# makes everything too easy I guess :)

Comment: You could still have `const` members, just see my updated answer. Stuff like pin addresses are unlikely to change.

Answer (score 3):

You have missed to specify the parameter types in your function definition according to your constructor function declaration:

```
Sonar(int,int,int,int); // Declaration
```

---

```
Sonar::Sonar(int trigLeft, int echoLeft, int trigRight, int echoRight) {
          // ^^^           ^^^           ^^^            ^^^
    // ...
}
```

Since the corresponding class member variables are declared as `const`

```
    const int triggerPinLeft,echoPinLeft,triggerPinRight,echoPinRight;
 // ^^^^^
```

they'll need to be initialized using the constructors member initializer list:

```
Sonar::Sonar(int trigLeft, int echoLeft, int trigRight, int echoRight) 
: triggerPinLeft(trigLeft)
, echoPinLeft(echoLeft)
, triggerPinRight(trigRight)
, echoPinRight(echoRight) {
}
```

That's the only way you can do it.

Comment: Dude you rock, I have fixed it all now. Thank you so so much, I know it seems simple but to me you are a hero I promise <3

Comment: And my robot is suddenly steering itself around objects like a boss. All of a sudden :D